# Covariance matrix for data

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

Assume $n*p$ data matrix $X$, where n is the number of observations and p is the number of features. We are interested in the covariance among features.

I have seen notations where covariance matrix is $X^{T}X$, $\frac{X^{T}X}{n-1}$, or $\frac{X^{T}X}{n}$. And apparently this also depends on whether the data is demeaned in each column? A bit confused here, will appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Might be a good idea to try to play with it. Imagine you have just two variables (two columns) and three observations (three rows). Write out the various expressions you gave explicitly in terms of observations and compare them to covariance definition.

Comment: In order the formulas are (a) not a covariance (it's a "sum of squares and products" matrix), (b) a covariance *estimator,* and (c) the covariance, all provided the columns are "demeaned."  This suggests what you want to research first is the definition of covariance.